# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel .Net 4.5.2

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Please someone help me, 
when I invoke 3rd party webservice, it shows :

```
Initializing
Generating WSDL
System.InvalidOperationException: General Error https://xxx ---> System.Net.WebException: There was an error downloading 'https:/xxx'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Discovery.DiscoveryClientProtocol.Download(String& url, String& contentType)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.Services.Discovery.DiscoveryClientProtocol.Download(String& url, String& contentType)
   at System.Web.Services.Discovery.DiscoveryClientProtocol.DiscoverAny(String url)
   at WebServiceStudio.Wsdl.ProcessRemoteUrls(DiscoveryClientProtocol client, StringCollection urls, XmlSchemas schemas, ServiceDescriptionCollection descriptions)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at WebServiceStudio.Wsdl.ProcessRemoteUrls(DiscoveryClientProtocol client, StringCollection urls, XmlSchemas schemas, ServiceDescriptionCollection descriptions)
   at WebServiceStudio.Wsdl.Generate()
```

I Already try using X509 Certificate, give user everyone full permission.

Comment: 1) Check the event log. 2) Can you reach the endpoint in a browser?

Comment: i cannot reach the endpoint because the webservice cannot be accessed from browser (https). What should I do ?

Comment: If the endpoint is not accessible *at all* this is not a programming issue. Talk to the supplier: Is the service up? Have you got the correct URL? Talk to your network administrator. Is the firewall blocking it?

Comment: the service is up, but it only can be connected by SOAPUI or Postman chrome. i doubt this is a programming issue too, but i need a prove before i escalate to my supplier.

Answer (score 0):

This may occur when the SSL certificate of the web service is not valid.

For a workaround, try the following code:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(delegate
{
    return true;
});
```

If this fixes your issue, then you should check the certificate on your machine.

As @dman2306 says, this is merely to check whether the certificate is the cause of your issues. **Do not use this in any production code.**

Comment: I feel it important to clarify what you imply: This code should NEVER be used in a production environment. @plusheen is suggesting you use this to test if you are having a certificate issue, NOT as a fix.